# Kusto malformed string literal

Tags: kql, kusto-explorer

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with below Kusto. I get error as below. I am trying to export data from my External table to a storage account

```
Error 

 Method 'ParseStringLiteral' invoked with an invalid argument 'literal', details: 'Malformed string literal: '<missing STRINGLITERALX>''
```

Query(logsKube is my external table name):

```
.export async compressed to json
  (
    h@"https://azdevstoreforlogs.blob.core.windows.net/exportinglogs;JnAU9secretmUGqNa4/4F8WE+MIWj8z9FQ==",
  )
  <|'logsKube'| limit 10000
```

New Query as suggested in answer below but get same error:

```
.export async compressed to json
  (
    h@"https://azdevstoreforlogs.blob.core.windows.net/exportinglogs;YBLLh3FY20tVI6a2fQ==",
  )
  <|external_table('logsKube')| limit 10000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is invalid.

1

[External table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/data-lake-query-data#querying-an-external-table) should be referenced as following:

```
external_table('logsKube ')
```

2
You have extra comma after the storage URL

Comment: get the same error. please see the question, I have updated the query now

Comment: that key is random alphabets..Its not correct :)

Comment: See updated answer